# Multi Client Architecture using Azure Api

Tags: wcf, azure-api-apps

I want to build a new mobile app backend. This backend might eventually support other types of clients such as desktop or traditional web application.

In the past for multi client applications I would use this stack of technologies. SQL Server -> Entity Framework -> TCP WCF Service Endpoint -> MVC Web Application or WPF Windows Application

I know I want my mobile client to be consuming a Restful Http Web API like the types you would host in the new Azure API product. But I'm not sure if I should still do the WCF layer or not.

Couldn't all my clients consume just the Web API now? Or would it still be wise to develop the WCF service and the layer Web API on top of that?

It just doesn't seem right to be using 2 different serialization technologies at the same time.

Comment: You should be able to replace the TCP WCF endpoint with Web API, just be aware that you'll be limited to strictly HTTP with Web API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could replace that with Web API and create a REST API but as Tim already mentioned on his comment, that is obviously just HTTP and not all the protocols WCF supports.

Having said that, API Apps have Swagger metadata to describe what the REST URIs (endpoints) can do (e.g. methods, content types, descriptions etc.). There are a lot of Swagger SDK generators which can read the Swagger metadata and generate the code you need to consume the REST API in your application for pretty much any language out there. For Visual Studio 2013 with the latest Azure SDK, you have this capability built in as well. This is pure code generation, no tight coupling or anything, we just generate the code you were supposed to write to consume the API.

Comment: The reason I was using TCP before was because I was told it delivered greater performance for clients that are behind the firewall. The one thing I didn't like about WCF SOAP Services was that you had to name everything GetObject() GetObjectByKey() GetObjectByName(), SaveObject() etc. You couldn't overload the method names.  But in Web API you just can use HTTP verbs to help describe your methods. I think that makes it easier on the eyes.  So I would like to use it for all clients if possible. How much faster is SOAP over TCP?

Comment: I don't think we can really quantify speed but generally HTTP is more costly and has a higher overhead. It really depends what you want to do. We can't really answer this question easily.